# HTML MVC C# Using a DropDownListFor to populate a ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems here. I would like the user to select a Team from a dropdownlist and have it do a method through jQuery or something, which will then populate the list box. I want it to show only the players for that team so I can trade them with another team.

What I have set up:
[Trade Players View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4NZl.png)

Currently, I have it made so it is showing all players in the ListBox.
I need it to display nothing until the user selects a Team.

Code for the TradePlayersView:

```
@model Baseball.Models.ViewModels.TradeVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TradePlayers";
}

<h2 align="center">Trade Players</h2>

<div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Select Teams</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Trade Player from Team:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Team1.Id, Model.Team1Items, "-Choose Team-", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Players1, Model.Players1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To Team:</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Team2.Id, Model.Team2Items, "-Choose Team-", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Players1, Model.Players1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Trade</button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Code for TradeVM:

```
public class TradeVM
    {
        public Team Team1 { get; set; }
        public Team Team2 { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Players1 { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Players2 { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Team1Items { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Team2Items { get; set; }

        public TradeVM()
        {
            Players1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Players2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Team1 = new Team();
            Team2 = new Team();
            Team1Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Team2Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public void SetPlayer1Items(IEnumerable<Player> players)
        {
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                Players1.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = player.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = player.LastName
                });
            }
        }

        public void SetPlayer2Items(IEnumerable<Player> players)
        {
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                Players2.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = player.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = player.LastName
                });
            }
        }

        public void SetTeam1Items(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
        {
            foreach (var team in teams)
            {
                Team1Items.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = team.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = team.Name
                });
            }
        }

        public void SetTeam2Items(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
        {
            foreach (var team in teams)
            {
                Team2Items.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = team.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = team.Name
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I just can't find a good answer around.. I appreciate any answers.

EDIT:
I probably should have included my code in the controller.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult TradePlayers()
        {
            var trade = new TradeVM();
            var manager = new TeamManager();
            var playerManager = new PlayerManager();

            //var team1 = manager.GetTeamById(trade.Team1.Id);
            //var team2 = manager.GetTeamById(trade.Team2.Id);
            //var player1 = team1.Players;
            //var player2 = team2.Players;

            trade.SetTeam1Items(manager.GetAllTeams());
            trade.SetTeam2Items(manager.GetAllTeams());
            trade.SetPlayer1Items(playerManager.GetAllPlayers());
            trade.SetPlayer2Items(playerManager.GetAllPlayers());

            // Need to specify players for that team.

            return View(trade);
        }

        //Work in progress
        //[HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult TradePlayers(TradeVM trade)
        //{
        //    var manager = new TeamManager();
        //    manager.TradePlayers(trade.Team1, trade.Team2, trade.Team1.Player, trade.Team1.Player);
        //    return RedirectToAction("Teams");
        //}
```

Comment: You need to add the Team's Id in the Player model, so you can filter it in the view with javascript, in the change event of the dropdown.

Comment: I do actually have the TeamId in the Player model. I'll try to mess around with the js.

Comment: You need cascading dropdownlists. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example